# Mongoose: Update dynamically generated collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

We have node.js project and using mongoose for mongodb operations.

A night job runs and dynamically creates a new collection named 'zonecountaggregate' in database.

I need to update this collection when some change happens on data from UI.

I've always worked when Model and schema is already defined and just refer it using below code to save or update data..

```
const account = await Account.findById(req.params.id);
....
const updatedAccount = await account.save();
```

My question is, how do I update this dynamic collection? 
I have first check if collection exists with that name and then if exists then update some field based on id.

I am doing this right now but cannot see result coming back.

```
const {
  ObjectId
} = require('mongoose').Types;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
var connection = mongoose.connection;
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

const test =  await db.collection('zonecountaggregate').find({_id: ObjectId("5e8ec95181d6ef6f64b69b2c")});
      console.log(test)
```

**we are using "mongoose": "^5.7.8"**

Answer (score 0):

This is how you update any field in mongoose after finding the collection : 
Model.where({ _id: id }).update({ $set: { title: 'words' }}). You have to set the fields that you want to update using your schema. For more info please check official Mongoose Docs.

Comment: Model is not defined in model folder in my project. this collection is being generated automatically everynight

Comment: How do I approach to find the collection and find the data?

Comment: If this is in your local machine , I would recommend to download MongoDb Compass , there you can see all your collections and DataBases and first at least try to save some data in your collection.